# Looping through an array object to find duplicates. Why is one element returning "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to implement a `unique(array)` function without using any array library methods (no `.push`, `.slice` or `.pop`, etc). I think I'm pretty close to the solution but the array I'm passing as a test `[2,2,3,3,4,2,2,2,2]` is returning `[2,undefined,3,undefined,4]` (it looks like `[2, ,3, ,4]` in the console) instead of `[2,3,4]`. Any idea what's happening here? I also tried adding an `if` statement to check if `array[i]` was undefined before assigning `returnArray[i]` to `array[i]` and that didn't work.

```
function unique(array){
    var tempObject = {};
    var returnArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if (!tempObject.hasOwnProperty(array[i])){
        tempObject[array[i]] = true;
        returnArray[i] = array[i];
      }
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: your script will fail on `[0, -0, 1, "1", [1], 2]`, which has 6 unique values

Comment: You're right :( Any suggestions?

Comment: [].indexOf() does a `===` compare, you could re-invent that...

Comment: Try: var key = array[i] + typeof array[i]; if ( tempObject.hasOwnProperty(key) ) { tempObject[key] = true; }

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'll have to try something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the exercise. and fun.
I think using `object[array[i]]` and `hasOwnProperty` is cheating. You say "not using any array methods", so you use object methods instead, kind of why bother?  and the second array? on top of the object keys, well that has totally lost the spirit of bare bones count the bytes coding.

You need something like this ugly unreadable collection of tokens. Yet very fast and only 5 extra references, elegant well in comparison. LOL

```
function unique(a){
 var i,j,t,b,c
 i=t=j=0
 while((b=a[i])!==c){
     j=0
     while(j<t&&a[j]!==b)j++
     if(j==t)a[t++]=b
     i++
 }
 while(i>=t)a[i--]=c
 a.length=t
 return a
}
```

Writes over its self and dereferences before using length to trim();

**Update** More details as this is now the answer.

What it does is move through the array reading each item until it reads an undefined item which is assumed to be the end of the array.

When each Item is read it searches through all the items previously read to check if there is a match, If no match is found then put the item back in the array at the write position as it must be unique so far, if a match has been found then drop the item and loop around to read the next item.

The read and write indexes. The read index is always ahead or equal to the write index, if it is found that an item already exists then that item is not put back into the array and the write index is not incremented letting the write index trail behind the read index.

At the end of the main loop the `writeIndex` may trail the read index leaving a number of items in the array that are not needed. I then loop through the all the items between the `readIndex` (currently === array.length) and write index dereferencing them with. This is strictly not needed as writing a shorter length to the Array length property has the effect of trimming the array, effectively doing the same thing. I added it in as I wanted to be pure to the challenge and not use an Array method to trim the array. (It's javascript some things are unavoidable)

So the function rewritten to comply  with JSLint style standards.

```
function unique(array) {
    'use strict';  // required by JSLint standards and really!!... never code JS without it
    // define all variables requierd
    var readIndex,
        searchIndex,
        writeIndex,
        arrayItem,
        undefinedRef;
    // you will notice that I do not indicate undefinedRef, it is undefined after all.
    readIndex = 0; // set the read index to start of the array
    writeIndex = 0; // set the write index to the start of the array
    // check if the readIndex has reached the end of the array
    while (array[readIndex] !== undefinedRef) {
        // get the item at the current readIndex. I could have made the code shorter
        // by not needing the arrayItem and just indexing the array at readIndex
        // in the next loop. But indexing into an array is always slower than
        // using a direct referance. Doing it this way adds a significant performance
        // improvement to the function.
        arrayItem = array[readIndex];
        searchIndex = 0; // set the search index to the start of the array
        // loop untill the search index reaches the write index or a match is found
        while (searchIndex < writeIndex && array[searchIndex] !== arrayItem) {
            searchIndex += 1; // increment the search index
        }
        // the seach index is at the write index then no match has been found
        // the new item must be unique so far so add it to the array
        if (searchIndex === writeIndex) {
            array[writeIndex] = arrayItem; // add the item at the write index
            writeIndex += 1; // increment the write index
        }
        // done for this item increment the readindex and loop
        readIndex += 1;
    }

    // dereferance any unwriten array items at the end of the array.
    // Dont really need this loop as setting the array length does the same thing
    while (readIndex >= writeIndex) {
        array[readIndex] = undefinedRef;
    }
    // remove the undefined items from the array by setting it lenght to the
    // number of items writen back into the array.
    array.length = writeIndex;
    // return the array.
    return array;
}
```

So that is how you write a mass of stuff about a function to make it look important.

**Update.** 
And another not using any of the array methods.

The ES6 version not as efficient but very simple, runs about 20% slower than the one above. Also uses more memory but should peek just over double the reference count of the one above. Also a cheat as checking for duplicates is now handled by `Set.add()` Though why slower than array indexed search who knows??

As a single line because it looks nice

`var unique=(a)=>{var c,i=0,s=new Set();while((b=a[i])!==c){s.add(b);a[i++]=c}return[...s]}`

And expanded a little (deliberately removed ; {} spaces, and use undefined c to test for undefined (end of array) ) I have assumed that no undefined values in the array.

This uses Set to cull duplicates. and then spread set back into array

```
var unique=(a)=>{       // arrow function
    var c,i=0,s=new Set()   // c undefined i=0 starting index and s a new Set
    while((b=a[i])!==c){
        s.add(b);   // add to the set till end of array
        a[i++]=c    // and dereference all array items as we go.
    }
    return [...s]    // convert to array with spread operator and return
}
```

Comment: It works. But I have idea why :P Can you point me to some resources to help me better understand your code?

Comment: I don't know of any good resources for this type of coding, but as you have made this the answer I will up date it with comments and a more detailed explanation very soon.

Answer (score 3):

try
`returnArray[returnArray.length] = array[i];` instead of `returnArray[i] = array[i];`

Comment: Actually...I spoke too soon, looks like I need to implement a different way.

Answer (score 2):

you should use index variable to assign value for returnArray. Because length of returnArray and array maybe difference.

```
function unique(array){
var index = 0;
var tempObject = {};
var returnArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if (!tempObject.hasOwnProperty(array[i])){
    tempObject[array[i]] = true;
    returnArray[index] = array[i];
    index++;
  }
}
return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: This approach works where array values are primitives, but it will fail for objects.